# Xamarin.Forms Control Template Binding Not Working

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I've specified a control template in my App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0"
                             Grid.RowSpan="3"
                             BackgroundColor="#2B653E"/>

                    <Label Grid.Row="1"
                           TextColor="White"
                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           FontSize="36"
                           FontFamily="TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT"
                           Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.HeadingText}"/>

                    <Image Grid.Row="2"
                           Grid.RowSpan="2"
                           Source="TGL_BG"/>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="4"/>

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can see I've got one of my controls databound:

```
Text="{TemplateBinding BindingContext.HeadingText}"
```

The control template works fine, I can add it to a page without any problems, except for the bound property doesn't display:

[image]

Here is my page code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="MyApp.Pages.ContactPage">
    <ContentView ControlTemplate="{StaticResource PageTemplate}">
        <StackLayout>
             <!-- Page content here, removed for brevity -->
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is my code behind:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MyApp.ViewModels;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.Pages
{
    public partial class ContactPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ContactPage(ContactPageViewModel viewModel)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            viewModel.Navigation = Navigation;
            BindingContext = viewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see I'm setting the binding context to the ViewModel (which works for everything outside the template). And here is my ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;
using MyApp.Helpers;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ContactPageViewModel : ViewModel
    {
        public string HeadingText = "Contact Us";

        //Other properties and commands here, removed for brevity
    }
}
```

As you can see I've got a public property here called 'HeadingText' which is what I'm binding to in the view.

I've read the documentation and a few examples/tutorials. According to what I can see this should work. Can anyone see what's wrong with this?

**EDIT:**

I've now got this working. In my ViewModel, I changed this:

```cs
public string HeadingText = "Contact Us";
```

to this:

```cs
public string HeadingText
        {
            get
            {
                return "Contact Us";
            }
        }
```

Leaving the question open now as hoping someone can provide an explanation.

Comment: Yeah,Problem is Using Properties.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) You can post answer and marked it.

Comment: If you want to have it a bit cleaner, you can write public string HeadingText => "Contact Us";

Answer (score 1):

binding only works with public properties

```
// this is a field, not a property
public string HeadingText = "Contact Us";

// this is a property
public string HeadingText
    {
        get
        {
            return "Contact Us";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, yeah I know that (it’s straight out of my post), I’m just struggling to understand it as it seems to violate encapsulation.